# How to correctly use get and post tests?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-testing

There get and post test:

```
def test_post_product(self):
        data = {
            'title': 'Chicken Breast',
            'proteins': 24.00,
            'carbs': 0.00,
            'fats': 3.00,
            'calories': 113
            }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('product-list'), data=json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)


        url = reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk':1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(ProductSerializer(data).data, response.data)
```

But in the line `self.assertEqual(HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)` I have 404 status code.
In the similar test with only get requests all work fine:

```
def test_get_product(self):
        product1 = Product.objects.create(title='Chicken Breast',proteins=24.00,carbs=0.00,fats=3.00,calories=113) 
        product2 = Product.objects.create(title='Tomatoes', proteins=0.90,carbs=3.90,fats=0.20, calories=18)
        url = reverse('product-list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(ProductSerializer([product1, product2], many=True).data, response.data)

        url = reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk':1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(ProductSerializer(product1).data, response.data)
```

What i do not correctly?

Comment: Can you check  reverse('product-list') in the shell and see if it is the same as your path too or not?

Comment: it's the same path, i've checked